# Python: socket.io client library

Tags: python, frameworks, client, socket.io

Im looking for a socket.io client implementation in python supporting the xhr-pollling or jsonp-polling transports. The only mature looking library I found Gevent-socketio seems only to support socket.io servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup. there's the [Python socketIO-client](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/socketIO-client)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to contributions from [Bernard Pratz](https://github.com/guyzmo) and [Francis Bull](https://github.com/franbull), [socketIO-client](https://github.com/invisibleroads/socketIO-client) supports xhr-polling and jsonp-polling as of v0.5.

```
pip install -U socketIO-client
```